# What does the Before compile event inside the Contact Form plugin do?

Tags: plugin-development, events, plugin-contactform

I see there is an undocumented event called `onBeforeMessageCompile` in the Contact Form plugin source:

```
Craft::import('plugins.contactform.events.ContactFormMessageEvent');
$event = new ContactFormMessageEvent($this, array('postedMessage' => $postedMessage));
craft()->contactForm->onBeforeMessageCompile($event);
```

My questions are:

1. How does one use this event? What can it be used for? and
2. Why is an `$event` object being instantiated [at this point in the controller](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ContactForm/blob/master/contactform/controllers/ContactFormController.php#L55)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does one use this event? What can it be used for?

It gives plugins a chance to manipulate the posted message to however they want instead of using the plugin's default implementation.  A plugin would listen to it like they listen to any [other event](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/hooks-and-events#events). Something like:

```
public function init()
{
    craft()->on('contactForm.onBeforeMessageCompile', function(Event $event) {
        $postedMessage = $event->params['postedMessage'];
        $event->messageFields = $postedMessage;

        // Do your thing.

        $event->message = "Your custom compiled message";
        $event->htmlMessage = "Your custom compiled HTML message";
    });
}
```

> Why is an `$event` object being instantiated at this point in the controller?

The short answer is "because that's how events work". :) Is there a particular thing that's confusing you?